# What is the use of "-u" option in cat command?

Tags: c, linux, unix, cat

I came across this in `man cat` (GNU/Linux).
The manual simply says `-u (ignored)` without explaining why.
Out of curiosity I searched on Google but it seems no one asked this before.
Then I looked at [other implementations](https://gist.github.com/pete/665971) of `cat`.
I noticed
Apple's cat also implements this option (see [cat.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-81/cat/cat.c)). In the source code it says

```
...
case 'u':
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    break;
...
```

I guess this option means 'unbuffered'. What is the inteneded use of this option? Why is it there and why is it ignored? I think there must be some reason for that.

Comment: If you're looking for information on the actual use of the option, you might have more luck on either the `SuperUser` or the `Unix and Linux` stack exchange websites, rather than SO.

Comment: [Perhaps seeing what `setbuf` does will help](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setbuf).

Comment: I guess it means `unbuffered`

Comment: How in the world does a *nix command question get 8 upvotes?

Answer (score 9):

Per [the POSIX standard for `cat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> cat [-u] [file...]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **OPTIONS**
>
> ...
>
> The following option shall be supported:
>
> **-u**
> Write bytes from the input file to the standard output without delay as each is read.

That could be implemented by disabling buffering on the output.

Answer (score 8):

option `-u` disables buffering to `stdout`.

GNU documentation reads:

> Use unbuffered I/O for stdout. Posix does not specify the behavior without this option.

which is perhaps indicating that the current default behavior of `cat` is to output without buffering.

Answer (score 8):

It is a POSIX compliant option for Unix/Linux.
GNU `cat` does this automatically and there is no way to turn it off. When specified, it is accepted but ignored because it has no effect on the behavior.

More details [`cat(1)`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/cat/):

> `-u`     Write  bytes from the input file to the standard output without delay as each is read.

Answer (score 8):

The idea behind `cat -u` is indeed that the output should be unbuffered, so that even if [`cat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) is in a pipeline, the data will be written promptly as it is read.

It can matter when you use `cat -u "$@" | …` and the input is, in fact, coming from a keyboard.

The chances are that GNU `cat` effectively works without buffering (using direct `read()` and `write()` calls), so the `-u` option is irrelevant — it always works in 'unbuffered mode'.

Answer (score 3):

The  `-u`   option  has  value in prototyping non-blocking reads from `FIFOs`. The intent is to
       support the following sequence:

> mkfifo foo>
>    cat -u foo > /dev/tty13 &
>    cat -u > foo
>
> It is unspecified whether standard output is or is not buffered in the
>   default case.  This
>          is sometimes of interest when standard output is associated with a terminal, since buffer-
>          ing may delay the output. The presence of the -u option guarantees that unbuffered I/O  is
>          available.  It  is implementation-defined whether the cat utility buffers output if the -u
>          option is not specified. Traditionally, the -u option is implemented using the  equivalent
>          of the setvbuf() function defined in the System Interfaces volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001.